# how to alert string is palindrome or not using webmethod when click on submit button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

```cs
[code page="c#"]  

[WebMethod]
    public static string check(string st)
    {
        String reverse = "";




        for (int i =  st.Length; - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse += st[i];
        }


        return reverse;
    }
```

I having dropdown from where when I select any option then depending upon that option when I give input into textbox and click on submit button than that value passed into webmethod using json.stringfy and showing the alert.but how to alert string is palindrome or not using webmethod when click on submit button?

Comment: If the string length is even, split in half, reverse the latter part, both parts should be the same. If the string length is uneven, find the middle character, ignore it, and use the above again. Getting the reverse of a string is easy using an array: `string.split('').reverse().join('');`

Answer (score 0):

You can change return type in your C# method to bool. Change your return like this:

```
return original.Equals(reverse)
```

After that in your success method in ajax:

```
function onSuccess(response) {
          var result = response.d;
          if(result) alert("Palindrome");
          else alert("Not palindrome");
        }
```

Also, you can keep your C# method, but change onSucces method only like this:

```
function onSuccess(response) {
              var result = response.d;
              if(result == $("#txt1").val()) alert("Palindrome");
              else alert("Not palindrome");
            }
```